# Load recent apps into GridView

Tags: java, android, gridview

I am creating a feature inside my Android app that will allow users to see their 6 last used apps in a gridview with only the application image. So far I have tried this:

```
        //Load recent used apps
    ActivityManager result = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    ArrayList<RecentTaskInfo> apps = (ArrayList<RecentTaskInfo>) result.getRecentTasks(10, ActivityManager.RECENT_WITH_EXCLUDED);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, apps);
    recentappsGridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But this only shows a lot of text in each row and column. How can I fix this/make it happen? Please note that I am already using a ListView within the same activity with a method for its click events.

Comment: Since you're using a generic ArrayAdapter it's trying to call the toString method on each of the RecentTaskInfo objects which results in your long string. You likely will need a custom adapter if you want to display images along with the proper text.

Comment: Yeah, figured that out. But i have no idea of where to start. I have been google'ing a lot

Answer (score 1):

Create a subclass of `ArrayAdapter`. Override `getView()`. Set up your cells to be images, not `TextView`. Use [`resolveActivityInfo()` on the `Intent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#resolveActivityInfo%28android.content.pm.PackageManager,%20int%29) you get from `baseIntent` in the `RecentTaskInfo` to get an `ActivityInfo` object. Use `icon` on `ActivityInfo` to populate your cell.

I haven't tried that recipe, but it should get you closer.

Comment: Thanks for anwer, but i'm really having trouble kinda doing what you mean.

Comment: @user1446632: You might consider using more than 13 words to explain precisely what it causing you difficulty.

Comment: To do all of you talk about. I'm not to good at it. And i think it's hard to add it to my code. Like "subclass", i have sure used it before, but i am not familiar with that name.

Comment: @user1446632: Newcomers to Java should learn Java before starting in on Android development. When you learn Java, you will learn what a subclass is.

Comment: I know, always when i ask, people answer, do a hello world app. PLEASE, i am asking a good question here, and please. If you cannot answer it. Dont waste my time.